# How to backup and restore (or create a snapshot) a linux machine with command line tools?

Tags: linux, snapshot

I have a remote ssh access to a linux machine, with a sudo user.
I don't have actual access to the machine itself.

I need a tool that will help me backup the machine and restore, or in other word - create a snapshot.

This tool should run in command line, and should preferably not reboot the machine.

I've tried the tar un-tar approach which is given here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

but it doesnt fit, because it only overrides and restores the files that already existed and were modified, but doesn't remove the files and directories that have been created since the backup.

Any idea of how to continue with this approach and achieve what I need, or alternately  another tool that I can use?

Comment: Advice about how to *write* such a backup program would be topical here, but using existing tools mostly isn't. Though I can't indicate it directly in the vote, [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you has LVM on that machine, you make a LVM snapshot first, then mount it and then copy its contents using `tar`, `cpio` or something like this.

```
$ sudo lvcreate -L1GB -n snap1 -s /dev/VG0/data1
$ sudo mount /dev/VG0/snap1 /mnt
$ cd /mnt; tar cvf /tmp/data1.tar .; cd /
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ sudo lvremove /dev/VG0/snap1
```

Tha main point here that you make the snapshot in a moment. And the copy data that are located on it. This process can be quite long, but it does not matter because you are copying a copy and the data on the snapshot will not change anymore.